# How to speed up Parallel::ForkManager in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am using EC2 amazon server to perform data processing of 63 files, 
the server i am using has 16 core but using perl Parallel::ForkManager with number of thread = number of core then it seems like half the core are sleeping and the working core are not at 100% and fluctuate around 25%~50%
I also checked IO and it is mostly iddling.

```
use Sys::Info;
use Sys::Info::Constants qw( :device_cpu );
my $info = Sys::Info->new;
my $cpu  = $info->device( CPU => %options );

use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $manager=new Parallel::ForkManager($cpu->count);

for($i=0;$i<=$#files_l;$i++)
{
        $manager->start and next;
        do_stuff($files_l[$i]);
        $manager->finish;
} 
$manager->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: Roughly how long is a call to `do_stuff`?

Comment: How busy is the CPU if you replace `$cpu->count` with `0`?

Comment: Does the `$cpu->count` match what you would expect by looking at `/proc/cpuinfo` ?

Comment: What `%options` are you passing to `Sys::Info`?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is - we can't tell you, because it depends entirely on what 'do_stuff' is doing.

The major reasons why parallel code doesn't create linear speed increases are:

- Process creation overhead - some 'work' is done to spawn a process, so if the children are trivially small, that 'wastes' effort.
- Contented resources - the most common is disk IO, but things like file locks, database handles, sockets, or interprocess communication can also play a part.
- something else causing a 'back off' that stalls a process.

And without knowing what 'do_stuff' does, we can't second guess what it might be.

However I'll suggest a couple of steps:

- Double the number of processes to twice CPU count. That's often a 'sweet spot' because it means that any non-CPU delay in a process just means one of the others get to go full speed.
- Try `strace -fTt <yourprogram>` (if you're on linux, the commands are slightly different on other Unix variants). Then do it again with `strace -fTtc` because the `c` will summarise syscall run times. Look at which ones take the most 'time'.
- Profile your code to see where the hot spots are. [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-6.04/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) is one library you can use for this.

And on a couple of minor points:

```
my $manager=new Parallel::ForkManager($cpu->count);
```

Would be better off written:

```
my $manager=Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( $cpu->count);
```

Rather than using indirect object notation.

If you are just iterating `@files` then it might be better to not use a loop count variable and instead:

```
foreach my $file ( @files ) { 
    $manager -> start and next;
    do_stuff($file);
    $manager -> finish;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, I finished executing the "do stuff" and got my results, after paying more attention it seems that the slowdown was related to commands which I call in the "do stuff" which worked with compressed files and not the parallel framework.